# How to calculate the pressure in a bag of water under an applied weight?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, fluid-dynamics, water, flow

I'm sorry is this is a simple question i am not very versed in physics, i tried searching google for this answer but didn't really know what i was looking at when i searched.

Here is my problem.

I have a sealed square bag with a port that is 4 CM long and .75 CM in diameter. Filled with water (Picture a large saline bag) with a maximum capacity of about 6K.

If I apply 5KG of weight evenly across the top of the bag what's the approximate pressure of the water being ejected from the port.

The bag is laying on a horizontal surface with the port to the side.

Comment: In the title you ask for the *rate*, in the body you ask for the *pressure*?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I just pictured water flowing out of the port so I wasn't sure what to call it, I know if I apply pressure it comes out faster, but essentially what I would like to know is the PSI of the water coming out of the Port to see the strength of an adapter I need for said port.

Comment: Why calculate the flow rate when you can easily measure it? Collect the water coming out, measure the volume and time taken. Or fill the bag with a known volume of water and time how long it takes for the bag to empy.

Comment: I noticed I got down voted by someone, is there any suggestions as to why that might of happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the pressure $p$ of the water adjacent to the weight $Mg$, divide the applied weight $Mg$ by the area $A$ of the bag which is in contact with the weight. ($M=5kg, g=9.8N/kg$.) If the weight is smaller than the bag then area $A$ is probably the area of one face of the weight; if the bag is smaller then $A$ is probably the area of one face of the bag. The pressure of water over this area is supporting the applied weight so $p \times A=Mg$.

Suppose the port is a vertical distance $h$ below the bottom of the applied weight. Then the pressure of the water in the sealed port will be $p+\rho g h$ where $\rho=1000kg/m^3$ is the density of water.

If water is being ejected through the port the pressure at the open end of the port will be the same as atmospheric pressure. I guess what you really want to know is the pressure when the flow has been stopped. That is $p+\rho gh$. It is the maximum pressure which the adapter (valve?) will need to handle.

There is also considerable atmospheric pressure ($15psi$) pushing on the weight and bag. However you can ignore this because it will also push on the back of the adapter as well as the front.